# Expansion vs Sparsest cut

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

let $G=(V,E)$ and $S\subsetneq V$ then expansion of set $S$ is

$$\alpha(S)=\frac{|E(S,\overline{S})|}{\min\{|S|,|\overline{S}|)\}}$$
where $\bar{S}=V\setminus{S}$ and $E(S,\bar{S})$ are edges between S and $\bar{S}$.
Expansion of graph G is
$$\alpha(G)=\min_{\emptyset\neq S\subsetneq {V}}\alpha(S)$$
Sparsity $\mathcal S_G$ of graph G is
$$\mathcal S_G=\min_{\emptyset\neq S\subsetneq {V}}\frac{|E(S,\overline S)|}{|S||\overline S|} $$
It is easy to see, that
$$\frac{n}{2} \mathcal{S}_G\leq \alpha(G) \leq (n-1)\mathcal{S}_G$$
where $n=|V|\.$
Solution for Expansion Problem is to find set $S\subsetneq V$ such that $\alpha(S)=\alpha(G)$
Solution for Uniform Sparsest Cut Problem is to find set $S\subsetneq V$ such that
$$\frac{|E(S,\overline S)|}{|S||\overline S|}=\mathcal S_G$$.
My question is, is there a graph for which there are different solution for Expansion Problem and for Uniform Sparsest Cut Problem?
Thank you for any ideas ..

Comment: For displayed equations, you need to include the punctuation within the equation (preferably offset by a `\;` space); otherwise it ends up on the following line, as you can see in your last equation.

Comment: I would post this to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/